# After Update to OS X El Capitan and Xcode(6.3.1) simulator not listed

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6.3, osx-elcapitan

Last day I updated to OS X El Capitan(10.11),When I run a project in Xcode (6.3.1), I found
the simulator list  disappeared.I click the "run" button, Xcode Alert :Xcode cannot run using the selected device.

[image: simulator list disappeared]

[image]

After that, I selected the simulator as the destination like below and run again,
But it don't work and show me: unable to boot the IOS simulator.
What's wrong?

[image: simulator as the destination]

Comment: What do you think to update Xcode to xcode7?

Comment: @Lorenzo He probably wants Xcode 6.3 because you can't get the iOS 7 simulator in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you update Xcode to 7.2 and download the iOS7.0

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when resizing the window too narrow.  If you widen the window, I suspect the list will re-appear.  If not, make sure you file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com with a screen capture video showing this happening.